# Res.send sends an empty object, even though console.log shows it isn't empty?

Tags: javascript, express

I am trying to use the google-sheets api with express and don't have much experience with javascript. I'm attempting to use pass a json object from express to react, but it seems that whenever I finally send the object, it just renders as empty on the frontend?

I've tried using res.body/res.data, but the object doesn't seem to have either. I've also tried to put as many awaits as I can everywhere to make sure the object is loaded in before sending, but nothing seems to do the trick. If I use res.json or res.send with just the response object, I get a circular structure converting to JSON error. Here is the code I'm working with.

```
async function docShit() {
  // Initialize the sheet - doc ID is the long id in the sheets URL
  const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(
    "--SPREADSHEET ID--"
  );

  // Initialize Auth - see https://theoephraim.github.io/node-google-spreadsheet/#/getting-started/authentication
  await doc.useServiceAccountAuth({
    // env var values are copied from service account credentials generated by google
    // see "Authentication" section in docs for more info
    client_email: process.env.GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
    private_key: process.env.GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY,
  });

  await doc.loadInfo(); // loads document properties and worksheets

  const sheet = doc.sheetsByTitle[--WORKSHEET TITLE--]; 
  const rows = await sheet.getRows(); // can pass in { limit, offset }

  return rows;
}

app.get("/home", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await docShit()
      .then((response) => {
        res.send(Promise.resolve(response)); //console log shows the object, but res.send just sends nothing??
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `res.send` at all in your code. Also, you use `await` and `.then` together, but I consider them alternatives. Try the following:

```js
app.get("/home", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    var response = await docShit();
    console.log(response);
    /* If response is circular, decide which parts of it you want to send.
       The following is just an example. */
    res.json(response.map(function(row) {
      return {id: row.id, cells: row.cells.map(function(cell) {
        return {id: cell.id, value: cell.value};
      };
    })};
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    next(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: If I replace the console.log with res.send, it causes those exact problems. If I res.json or res.send just the response object, it says I'm sending a circular json, but if I put it in Promise.resolve as I've done in the code above, it sends an empty object.

Comment: In that case, you must construct a non-circular "subset" of the information. See my edited answer.

Comment: That was the solution I came up with originally, but I thought I was just approaching it wrong. Thank you for the help!